# iPhone SDK: eMail application source code

Tags: ios, email, ios4

I want to make an emailing application but I wanted to know if there is maybe already an application that provides their source code so I could get a head start. Like maybe just the simple concept of placing emails in a table view and retrieving them from a server. If there is anything out there please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a google search, you should be able to find what you are looking for.  Here are some I found.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/

http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=ECkJh2mnFc8&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DECkJh2mnFc8

The geeky lemon drop one is pretty good.